# Is it true that Lao-Tzu is actually Siddha Bhoganāthar?

Tags: belief, history, other-religions, guru

[Marshall Govindan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marshall_Govindan)  wrote the book [Babaji and the 18 Siddha Kriya Yoga Tradition](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1895383005).
Here is the summary of Chapter 8. Siddha Boganathar:

> An Oceanic
>   Life Story. A mission to China and transmigration. Transformation of
>   his physical body. **Becomes known as Lao-Tzu, founder of Taoism**. Return
>   to India. Establishes shrine at Katirgama, and attains soruba samadhi.
>   Second mission to China. Current activities. Selections from the
>   writings of Siddha Boganathar.

See also the webpage [Siddha Bhoganāthar: An Oceanic Life Story](http://palani.org/bhogar_biography.htm).

**Question**: Is it true that Lao-Tzu is actually [Siddha Bhoganāthar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogar)?

Comment: Only a seer can validate this so it is unlikely you will receive an answer. However, it may be believed that those who have done some tapasya in their previous lives receive births that help them complete their penance and attain brahmatvam. If you were a non-vaidika in your previous birth but lived mostly accordingly to vedic/vedantic norms (even if unwittingly), you will receive a birth in the vedic religion. Goes to show that all humans are after all Hindus.